# typescript getter / setter on array property

Tags: arrays, typescript, design-patterns, getter-setter

Is there a good way to use getter / setter pattern for array properties?

For example:

```js
export class User {

  private _name: string;

  set name(value: string) {
    this._name = value;
  }

  get name(): string {
    return this._name;
  }

  private _roles = new Array<string>();

  set roles(value: Array<string>) {
    this._roles = value;
  }

  get roles(): Array<string> {
    return this._roles;
  }

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

While changing user.name fires the setter method, adding or removing items from roles does not.

Now i think i understand why it does not fire the setter, because adding items to the array does not change the pointer but merely adds to the already allocated space (correct me if i'm wrong).

How can we get the desired getter / setter behaviour on array properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said doing something like `user.roles.push('my-role')` will merely mutate the existing array. Instead of giving direct access to the array through the `roles`-setter, you could add methods like `addRole` and `removeRole`. Then you can implement whatever logic you need when adding or removing to the `roles` array, keeping it totally private.